# Extension of an invertible operators on a separable Hilbert space

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $T$ a bounded linear operator on $H$.
If $T$ is onto and one-to-one on a dense subspace of $H$, then is $T$ invertible on $H$?

In other words, if $T$ is invertible on a dense subspace of $H$, then is $T$ so on H?

I think this is not true, but I have not constructed a counterexample. If it is not true, what additional condition is necessary to be true?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Let $H=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ and consider the dense subspace $H_0$ of sequences with finitely many nonzero entries. Define 
$$
T(a_1,a_2,\ldots)=\left(a_1,\tfrac12 a_2,\tfrac13 a_3,\ldots\right).
$$
Then $T$, on $H_0$, is clearly bounded, one-to-one, and onto. But it is not bounded below, so it cannot extend to an invertible operator (it does extend, of course, every bounded operator does). The extension of $T$ to $H$ is compact, which is another way to see that it cannot be invertible.

Also, note that this $T$ is not invertible on $H_0$ (the inverse it not bounded). If $T$ has an inverse bounded in $H_0$, then it will extend to an invertible operator on $H$.